# Bacula Backup: Keep files from x days back

Tags: bacula

I try to setup Bacula as backup solution.
The requirement is to take daily full backups and to keep 20 last jobs, jobs for example 21 days back to be deleted. 
So in case of recovery to be able to go 20 days back, how I can do this ?
Thank you a lot!

Comment: I'll recomend to configure the retention policy, thus you should be able to keep 20 last jobs and delete the following ones. This link might be helpful http://www.bacula.org/5.2.x-manuals/en/main/main/Automatic_Volume_Recycling.html

Comment: in theory yes, in reality with bacula / bareos how this is possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to physically delete the jobs and so the files older than 21 days, you can play with the volume retention.

If you only use the job retention, bacula will not delete the old files in the old jobs. It will just delete their entries in the database.

In your example, to delete (purge) the  old saves, you can configure to have a volume per day and a retention of yours volumes equal to 20 days.

You can use this doc of the bacula website to understand the differentes options :

```
          because job count or size limit exceeded
  Append  ---------------------------------------->  Used
    ^                                                  |
    | First Job writes to        Retention time passed |
    | the volume                   and recycling takes |
    |                                            place |
    |                                                  v
  Recycled <-------------------------------------- Purged
                 Volume is selected for reuse
```

The append of your volume can be one day or one job, and the used 20 days.

This example is only available if you want to have one job/volume/day.